# how to centering "align-vertical" facebook like button?

Tags: html, css, facebook

I want to center the facebook like button vertically. how to do that?

heres my website:
http://feednews.id/

see the like button on the top right of the page?
why it gets aligned to the top? i already use

```
style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"
```

Please, please, please help me. as I already try to figuring it out for all day long. I'm now got headache :(

I prefer not to change any css file. can i still do that?

Heres the facebook button code that i use: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n18mcyjn/)

Comment: I don't see any like button on the website, can you please edit your question and post [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _“why it gets aligned to the top?”_ – because you did absolutely nothing that would cause it to be aligned differently? How absolutely _not_ specific to the like button this issue is, you can easily see when you replace it with a simple `<strong>D’oh!</strong>` - that just gets aligned to the very top as well.

Answer (score 1):

use `margin` property:

```
._2tga._3e2a {
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0 4px 0 6px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate your inline-styles using `;` not "and"

Remove:

```
and vertical-align: middle;
```

and update it: `vertical-align:middle`

Do not use "and" in between styles.

Comment: lol. sorry typos. i dont use "and" in my style. I know basic css and html. :)